# How to remove elements from list while iterating

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

hey I have a issue where i want to remove some elements from a list, the problem is it change the index and them don't know how to remove the index that actually need next

so it remove "salt" but them it dont remove "sugar", i asume is because the index pass from 0-9 to 0-8 in the next iteration

result it give: `["apple", "orange", "pepper", "orange", "cake", "tree", "tree", "leaf", "sugar"]`

result I want: `["apple", "orange", "pepper", "orange", "cake", "tree", "tree", "leaf"]`

```
#list to match
fi_names = ["apple", "orange", "pepper", "orange", "cake", "tree", "tree", "leaf"]

#list to modify to match the first one
se_names = ["apple", "orange", "pepper", "orange", "cake", "tree", "tree", "leaf", "salt", "sugar"]

#susbtract list to get x_names = ["salt", "sugar"]
x_names = list( set(se_names) - set(fi_names) )

#iterate in the second list to try to remove the extra elements by index
for i, e in enumerate(se_names):
    if e in x_names:
        se_names.pop(i)

print(se_names)
```

Comment: Generally, the better way is not to remove items from the list at all, but create a _new_ list that only has the the items you want.

Comment: Better to create a new filtered list if you can, otherwise you can iterate over the reversed range of the length of the list removing items from n down to 0 as appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in this case is just remve elements on the list by their names, by using the `.remove` list method:

```
for name in x_names:
    se_names.remove(name)
```

This, of course, implies in a quadratic iteration, which can be a problem for big lists, and a large removal list (say... a 10 million item list, and a 1 million list of words to be removed).

So, another approach is simply build a new list altogether, excluding the items to be removed:

```
x_names = set(se_names) - set(fi_names) 

se_list = [item for item in se_list if item not in x_names]
```

Keeping x_names as a set, and not converting it to a list (which is also uneeded in your approach) is important here, as the complexity to check if an item is in a set is O(1), in contrast with O(n)  if it is a list (taking you back to a quadratic approach).

This approach could do even the 10 million list with 1 million removals in a time close to 1 second (Just took 1.19s in my 2021 i7 - using a single core) - while the in-place removal from the first approach took 7 seconds to remove 10_000 items from a 100_000 length list)

Comment: these version also worked, Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* modify a list while iterating over it.

*Do* create a new list containing the items you want.

```
se_names = [x for x in se_name if not (x in x_names)]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, took me a moment to understand this format of writing it, still too new I guess, I tested and write it in this other way too and manage to get the same result


item = list(se_names)

for x in item:
    if x in x_names:
        se_names.remove(x)